# problem of setup of VS2019 for using c# dll at c++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I want to use c# code at c++ for selenium. However, while following the post about dll export in Google, The author of the article explained using vs2010, but vs2019 has no 'assembly information' button in the properties of the project.

for dll export, i need exposing assembly at COM. but i cant find that. 
because I can't find this problems about it anywhere. I ask the question here 
where is this?

Comment: You probably created a .NET Core project rather than a .NET Framework project.

Comment: @John oooopss.. thank you